# Deleted question in questions queue

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, caching

I was on the *Newest questions* tab for WPF, and I found the below shown question in the question queue.

[image: Question]

When I tried to go to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657998/list-of-strings-not-displaying-correctly-in-datagrid), I got to know it was already deleted. Why does the site show such a question in the question queue?

Comment: That view is not particularly fast to update, so easily has stale information.  As usual, it is caching.

Comment: Can't SE make it fast to update just like the new question is added, deleted question gets removed from the queue?

Comment: Maybe you need to refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refreshing the page, and if that doesn't work then it might be because that particular tab doesn't update too fast so you might find some recently deleted questions in there. I think it is caching because I have had that problem before.